# How can I make the output print out a list of numbers?

Tags: python, list

So what I'm trying to do is find the total number of 1 dollar, 2 dollar, 5 dollar and 10 dollar bills needed to equal a number `v: int` and i'm kinda stuck on how to do it...
Here is my code so far..

```
def coinChange(v: int):
    while x == 1 and x == 2 and x == 5 and x == 10:
        if x + x + x + x == v:
            return x
```

Like its definitely wrong, so what am I doing wrong here and what should I do to fix it? Btw, the output should be a list, so like... if `coinChange(38)` is the input, the output should be `[10,10,10,5,2,1]` What is the right code to make sure I get the right output?

Comment: I hope you realize that a number cannot be equal to 1 AND equal to 2.  What you need to do is start with the largest bills.  You can use `v//10` 10 dollar bills.  Subtract that amount from the total and then try for 5 dollar bills.

Comment: Your `while` condition will always be false.  `x` cannot be equal to two different values, much less four different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use integer division (`//`) and modulus (`%`) operations to determine the number of each denomination required.

```
def coinChange(v: int):
    tens = v // 10
    remainder  = v % 10
    fives = remainder // 5
    remainder = remainder % 5
    twos = remainder // 2
    ones = remainder % 2

    coins = [10 for n in range(tens)]
    coins += [5 for n in range(fives)]
    coins += [2 for n in range(twos)]
    coins += [1 for n in range(ones)]

    return coins
```

The code can be reduced using a loop:

```
def coinChange(v: int):
    coins = [10, 5, 2, 1]
    change = []
    for c in coins:
        change += [c for n in range(v // c)]
        v = v % c
    return change
```

The result for both implementations will be the same:

```
coinChange(38) # [10, 10, 10, 5, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead.

```
def change(amount):
    money = ()
    for coin in [10,5,2,1]:
        num = amount/coin
        money += (coin,) * num
        amount -= coin * num

    return money
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest logic and you can understand it make sure to start with greater like check 10 first then 5 and then  2 and then 1

```
def coinChange(x):
    coins = []
    while x != 0:
        if x >= 10:
            x = x - 10
            coins.append(10)
        elif x >= 5:
            x = x - 5
            coins.append(5)
        elif x >= 2:
            x = x - 2
            coins.append(2)
        elif x >= 1:
            x = x - 1
            coins.append(1)
    print(coins)
            
coinChange(38)
```